# Nagios check_bgp_neighbors plugin showing critical status

Tags: monitoring, ubuntu-12.04, bgp, nagios

I am trying to configure nagios check_bgp_neighbors plug-in on Ubuntu and followed [README file](http://exchange.nagios.org/components/com_mtree/attachment.php?link_id=1559&cf_id=24) of check_bgp_neighbors plug-in. I have made following changes:

```
define command{
    command_name    check_bgp_all
    command_line    $USER1$/check_bgp_neighbors -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -C $USER3$ -n $ARG1$ -n $ARG2$
    }
```

to

```
define command{
        command_name    check_bgp_all
        command_line    /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_bgp_neighbors.sh -H xx.xx.xx.49 -C snmpName -n xx.xx.xx.50
```

And

```
define service{
    use             server-service
    hostgroup_name          svc-bgp1
    service_description     BGP Check 1
    check_command           check_bgp_all!10.0.0.1!172.16.0.2
    }
```

to

```
define service{
        use                             generic-service
        hostgroup_name                  svc-bgp1
        service_description             BGP Check 1
        check_command                   check_bgp_all!xx.xx.xx.50
        }
```

xx.xx.xx.49 is the IP of the host router and xx.xx.xx.50 is the IP of eBGP neighbour.

**Status information:**

line: neighbor:xx.xx.xx.50:sent:78838:received:9769

Failed: status:6 prefixes:16 sent:0 received:1

**Log**

```
[1353997904] SERVICE NOTIFICATION: router1;router1;BGP CHECK 2;CRITICAL;notify-service-by-email;line: neighbor:xx.xx.xx.50:sent:78842:received:9772
[1353997904] SERVICE NOTIFICATION: router1;router1;BGP CHECK 2;CRITICAL;notify-service-by-sms;line: neighbor:xx.xx.xx.50:sent:78842:received:9772
```

Why does it show critical status????

**I am not getting response for this question, if you need additional information please  mention it in comment.**

**Updadte**

```
#./check_bgp_neighbors.sh -H xx.xx.xx.49 -C myCommunity -n xx.xx.xx.50
```

output:

```
line: neighbor:xx.xx.xx.50:sent:80327:received:11122
Failed: status:6 prefixes:16 sent:0 received:0
```

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: Its showing critical status, I cannot detect the problem.

Comment: Where can I add snmp version???

Comment: Your changes aren't consistent with each other. You should really read the "Macros and how they work" docs page. (But this isn't really related to your problem.)

Comment: Your question isn't really a nagios problem; it's a "why doesn't this plugin behave as I expect?". Show us the output of a manual CLI test with "-v" added to the end.

Comment: Why do you bother to obfuscate the IP addresses in the conf snippets, but leave them in the "Log" section? ;-)

Comment: @Keith... :)...I just copied the log from log file and forgot to change the IP address :D. I am new with nagios, even I don't know how to get the output of a manual CLI for this situation. I am learning about this and I will provide the the output of a manual CLI ASAP.

Comment: Just run the plugin manually, on the command line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully configured nagios BGP monitoring plug-in on my server. But I have used check_bgp plug-in instead of check_bgp_neibor. Here are the links I have followed:

http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Network-Protocols/BGP-2D4/check_bgp/details

http://www.linuxscrew.com/2012/04/05/nagios-cisco-bgp-peers-monitoring-check_bgp/